# Consultation on ng-repeat variable html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I'm carrying a $ ionicPopup with a variable that I get from my webservice. The problem that I have is not as filling into a variable. I leave my code:

```
     if(data.Count > 0){
        $scope.areas = data.Area;     
        var contentHtml = '<ul ng-repeat="area in data.Area"><li>{{area.name}}</li></ul>';
        $ionicPopup.show({
            title: 'Areas disponibles',
            subTitle: '',
            content: contentHtml,
            scope: $scope,
            buttons: [{
              text: 'Salir',
              onTap: function(e) {

              }
            }]
          })
      }
```

This obviously does not work and I'm looking to be able to load that variable in the ng-repeat, if someone could help me appreciate it.

Comment: Can you post what data.Area is?

Comment: Try ng-repeat="area in areas" instead of "data.Area". Since you only show that you scoped areas. Shoudn't change something if you have scope data too.

Comment: @Okazari Man, this worked perfect, you could put it as answer if someone else needs it? The other, could you explain me what is the difference of "instead of" data.Area "had not seen that ever.

Comment: Actually the "instead of "data.Area"" was just a part of my sentence and not code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML you can only use scoped var (ie : $scope.data mean that data is scoped).

data.Area isn't accessible into your html.

Doing this :

```
$scope.areas = data.Area;
```

You make it accessible as "areas" in your html.

Using ng-repeat like this :

```
ng-repeat="area in areas"
```

Will do the trick.